# how to prevent adf inputFile control from changing its state after file uploading

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

Is there an easy way to prevent  from changing it's state ? I meant when I upload file inputFile UI render itself in a different fashion and I cannot find easy way to prevent it. Is it doable in some other way then altering it's renderer ? 
I'm using environment from jDeveloper 11.1.1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None that I know of. I find the behavior annoying as well but I think they designed it that way because the moment the file has already been submitted(whether by autoSubmit or just a regular submit) it doesn't submit it again. Have you tried resetting/clearing the value after the first submit? Maybe that will reset the inputFile's state as well.

Comment: Yes it's resenting inputFile state. It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it good enough. Thx :) I'm ashamed of myself I did not try it earlier...
Unfortunately I cannot vote You up yet :(

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I'm trying to get the oracle-adf section alive here(the OTN forums for ADF has too many nonsense questions popping up).